# Why $\sigma_i(A)^2 |a_i|^2 + \dots + \sigma_q(A)^2 |a_q|^2 \leq \sigma_i(A)^2$ holds?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $q = \min {m, n}$ with singular values $\sigma_i(A) \geq \dots \geq \sigma_q(A)$ and $a_i^2 + \dots +a_q^2 = 1$. Could you please someone help to understand why the following inequality holds?

$$\sigma_i(A)^2 |a_i|^2  + \dots + \sigma_q(A)^2 |a_q|^2 \leq \sigma_i(A)^2$$

<sup>This is part of the proof of Lemma 3.3.15 in Topics in Matrix Analysis,Roger A. Horn.</sup>

Comment: Obvious: the barycenter of points in an interval $[a,b]$ is smaller or equal to $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that:

$$ \sigma_{j}(A) \leq \sigma_{i}(A) , \forall j \in [i,q]$$

And as the singular values are non-negative:

$$ \sigma_{j}(A)^2 \leq \sigma_{i}(A)^2 , \forall j \in [i,q]$$

Thus the left hand side is less than:

$$ \sigma_{i}(A)^2 (a_{i}^2 + \cdots + a_{q}^2) = \sigma_{i}(A)^2 $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!